# Is there way to force SPIR-V assembly function to accept both Private and Function storage class arrays?

Tags: vulkan, hlsl, spir-v, spir

I am in the process of writing a binary processing module for SPIR-V shaders to fix alignment issues with float4x3[6] matrices because of driver bugs. Right now i have:

- injected necessary appropriate OpTypes and OpTypePointers.
- processed the binary to change constant buffer members from float4x3[6] to vec4[18]
- injected function properly unpacking vec4[18] into float4x3[6] accepting vec4[18] as a pointer to Uniform array 18.
- created Private storage qualifier matrix unpack targets as OpVariables.(Private in SPIR-V just means invocation-level global...).
- injected preambles about composite extraction and construction to call my new function. (since from what im seeing we need to copy arguments from constant buffers to functions always, so thats what I do).
- called the function from entrypoint, for every float4x3[6] member to have ready unpacked matrices when main() starts.
- changed OpAccessChain operations that referenced given members in constant buffers and swapped them with access chains referencing my new Private targets.

But now i ran into trouble. It looks like a function in SPIR-V can either accept Private or Function storage qualifier pointers. Not both. Is there any way i can tell SPIR-V "Yeah, you can dump both of those storage classes here as arguments"?

Or do i need to rework my solution to utilize Function storage class matrix targets, and inject them and calls to unpack them every single time they are used in a new function? This seems much less elegant since there might be way more unpack operations then. And much less hassle-free, since i would have to scan every OpFunction block separately and inject OpVariables with Function storage into every block that uses the matrices.

My problem is, after all this machinery is done my targets are living as OpTypePointer of Private Storage Duration. Therefore i cannot use them in ANY SPIR-V function generated from HLSL, since they take OpTypePointers of Function duration. My unpack function is sole exception to this since i injected it directly in SPIR-V asm, byte by byte and was able to precisely tune OpFunctionParameters in header.

Comment: "*they take OpTypePointers of Function duration*" How does that work? What does the compiler do if you pass a parameter that is part of something that isn't of Function duration? A global variable, SSBO, or something similar?

Comment: Compiler tries really, really hard not to use Private variables. If you define something as a global, compiler will try to make it a Function variable anyway and inject it in every applicable scope. Or it will generate two copies of the function, one for Private, one for Function. As for UBO/SSBO parameters the compiler simply copies things to new OpVariables of function duration, and passes them on, since they have to be passed as a copy anyway.

Comment: "*fix alignment issues with float4x3[6] matrices because of driver bugs*" Are you sure those are "driver bugs"? Because unless you're doing scalar layout (or is row-major), a 4x3 matrix is a matrix containing 4 columns with rows of 3 elements each. That's basically an array of `float3`. And Vulkan *requires* that `float3`s be aligned to that of `float4` (again, unless you use `scalar` layout). That's not a "driver bug"; that's just how alignment has to work in Vulkan. So maybe switch to row-major ordering for them (with corresponding changes in your main code).

Comment: The scalar layout blocks do not behave as they should on this hardware, and IHV has confirmed that their driver implementation is buggy. We have to work around that since shader code runs on myriad of other platforms, and having platform-specific fixes in HLSL would be messy. Thats why im doing this at SPIR-V level, to be able to leave standard HLSL semantics without weird unpacking hacky functions and modifying thousands of shaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of calling conventions. Or rather, the *lack* of calling conventions in SPIR-V.

Higher-level languages like GLSL and HLSL have calling conventions. They explain what it means for a function to take an input parameter and how that relates to the argument being given to it.

SPIR-V doesn't have calling conventions in that sense. Or more to the point, you have to *construct* the calling conventions you want using SPIR-V.

Parameters in HLSL are [conceptually always passed by copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-function-parameters). If the parameter is an input parameter, then the copy is initialized with the given argument. If the parameter is an output parameter, the data from the function is copied into the argument after calling the function.

The HLSL compiler must implement this in SPIR-V. So if a function takes a `struct` input parameter, that function's input parameter must be *new storage* from any existing object. When a caller tries to call this function, it must create storage for that parameter. That storage will use the `Function` storage qualifier, so the parameter also uses that qualifier.

SPIR-V requires that pointer types specify the storage qualifier of the objects they point to. This is important, as how the compiler goes about generating the GPU assembly which accesses the object can be different (perhaps drastically). As such, a function cannot accept a pointer that points to different storage classes; the function has to pick one.

So if your SPIR-V adjustment system sees a function call whose source data comes from something you need to adjust, then you have two options:

1. Create a new function which is a copy of the old one, except that it takes a `Private` pointer.
2. Follow the calling convention by creating `Function`-local storage and copying from your `Private` data into it prior to calling the function (and copying back out if it is an output parameter). There's probably code to do that sitting there already, so you probably only need to change where it copies from/to.

Comment: Thank you. I think i will go down with copying arguments from Private to Function qualifier OpVariables.

Comment: If i might have another question, how would i go about copying float4x3[6] private to float4x3[6] Function? I have already found appropriate place for injection (under given function first OpLabel), but... how to approach copying itself? Do i need to do OpLoad->OpStore, or do i need to OpLoad -> OpCompositeExtract every indice -> OpCompositeConstruct -> OpStore? I cannot find anything concrete in the spec regarding how to copy such variables.